# Installing PostgreSQL ODBC drivers on mac for use in the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard

Tags: mysql, postgresql, odbc

I want to use the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard to convert a PostgreSQL database into MySQL, but am unable to correctly install the odbc drivers.  I downloaded the tarball and followed the installation instructions exactly for Mac OS X (http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/set-up-and-configure-postgresql-odbc-drivers-for-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/) and did not receive any errors during this process. Obviously something went wrong, however, because the necessary command for the next step (iodbcadm-gtk) is not installed anywhere.  I have checked in any location I can think of to ensure this is not simply a path issue.  Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Additional note:
The only files it does install are /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.la and /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so

Comment: I was not able to figure this out, but ended up concluding that the errors ultimately have to do with the 32-bit nature of the mysql workbench for Mac.  I ended up getting it working on an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to download odbc manager for mac to be able to configure your driver

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl895